# How to create behaviour flow charts?

Tags: analytics, reporting, powerbi, business-intelligence

Do you know any way for creating **Behaviour flow charts** like those used in google analytics?

ie:

[image]

I'd like to report the behavior of objects along their lifecycle.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to find existing custom visual that does that, for example [here](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps?product=power-bi-visuals&page=1&src=office).

If there are none, your only option is to [develop your own](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tsmatsuz/2016/09/27/power-bi-custom-visuals-programming/).

Many PowerBI visuals use D3 engine, so you may have luck in utilising an existing D3 visual, [for example this one](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/) .